PRoblem with blockchain transaction
I have a big problem, in 2009 I did some mining but then I let it go.
I had lost the disk I had done it on so I didn't think about it anymore
also because I couldn't remember how many bitcoins I had mined.
Now I found the disk again and some bitcon I had mined.
Problem as soon as I open the program, it shows me the balance and I can see how many bitcoins I had mined and in the description of each block there is (as you can see below)
Status: 923 confirmations
Date: 5/19/2009 9:32 pm
[...]
As soon as it starts synchronizing the headers though, the problem arises.
From
Status: 923 confirmations
Date: 5/19/2009 9:32 pm
to
Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 5/19/2009 9:32 pm
Do you have any ideas to recover these bitcoins?
Thanks
Here is the full description
Status: 923 confirmações
Date: 19/05/2009 21:32
Source: Michey
Crédito: 50.00000000 BTC
Valor líquido: +50.00000000 BTC
ID da transação: 0a3594b67d35e5cb846ef5eabd2d76c256a04769c8a70d6c22d0fe0155665d1b
Tamanho tota da transação: 107 bytes
Tamanho virtual da transação: 107 bytes
Index da saída: 0
to this
Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 19/05/2009 21:32
Source: Michey
Credit: (not accepted)
Net amount: 0.00000000 BTC
Transaction ID: 0a3594b67d35e5cb846ef5eabd2d76c256a04769c8a70d6c22d0fe0155665d1b
Total transaction size: 107 bytes
Virtual transaction size: 107 bytes
Output index: 0
...

Transaction ID 0a3594b67d35e5cb846ef5eabd2d76c256a04769c8a70d6c22d0fe0155665d1b is not found by the blockchain explorers blockchair.com & blockchain.com, which suggests it was never confirmed.
In that case the 50 BTC mining reward does not exist.
This can't explain why the program showed 932 confirmations. Maybe back in 2009 someone carried out an eclipse attack to fool your Bitcoin node and feed it a fake blockchain to trick you? Maybe you were mining an altcoin that is now defunct? Maybe they were testnet coins?
Whatever the reason, that money does not exist now and cannot be made to exist.

I know this is the problem
I'm potentially rich but I can't access my bitcoins because they seem to have magically disappeared.
Does anyone have any idea where they might have gone?
i read somewhere that there was a time when there was an option to change the transaction id from the nodes authorizing the transaction. is that possible or am i misunderstanding?
Thank's

Sadly, you are not potentially rich. That transaction is a mirage, it does not represent real Bitcoin money. It hasn't gone anywhere because the current Bitcoin blockchain says it never existed.

I agree with you, but then why does it tell me that it was accepted? where did they go? and there are many--with different values of confirmations, from 101 to 300 or so.
other example
Status: 9254 confirmations
Date: 2/18/2009 09:56
Source: Generated
Credit: 50.00000000 BTC
Net amount: +50.00000000 BTC
Transaction ID: dc05edbf9f2f3c8b111b707fd2dadaee354922fa7940accee2df3429f75d9235
Transaction total size: 107 bytes
Output index: 0

Those transactions do not exist in the Bitcoin blockchain, maybe you were mining an altcoin that is now defunct?

It is possible that you mined a stale block, a block that was competing with another block at the same height that never became part of the best chain. Either way, I can confirm that the transaction is not part of the Bitcoin blockchain, nor does it appear in any of the altcoins indexed by blockchair.com.
